# php cURL ignoring variables in url

Tags: php, curl

I am working on a crawl script to read ratings from a webshop.

The curl part is now making me problems, since it does not retrieve the right content.

I select the urls from the database in batches with an ajax script. I give the curl the correct url to the page with the ratings, but Curl is retrieving the page without the variable part in the url.

This is the url I am passing onto Curl: `$actualurl`

http://www.domain.com/epages/xxx.sf/de_DE/?ObjectPath=/Shops/15456062/Products/%22Briefkastenst%C3%A4nder%20Bobiround%22/SubProducts/%22Briefkastenst%C3%A4nder%20Bobiround%20gr%C3%BCn%20RAL6005%22&ViewAction=ViewProductRating

(This is the page I want to read all 6 ratings (Produktbewertungen) from.)

But with the curl call I get contents from this page, which is the same without the viewAction, I echoed the output

http://www.domain.com/epages/xxx.sf/de_DE/?ObjectPath=/Shops/15456062/Products/%22Briefkastenst%C3%A4nder%20Bobiround%22/SubProducts/%22Briefkastenst%C3%A4nder%20Bobiround%20gr%C3%BCn%20RAL6005%22

My Curl call looks like this:

```
            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $actualurl);              
            //read content of $url
            $result = curl_exec ($ch);
            curl_close ($ch);
```

Why is Curl ignoring the last part of the url (with `&ViewAction=ViewProductRating`)

Thank you so much I am still new to curl!

**EDIT**

I build the url mentioned above from 4 parts. The parts are following:

```
$domainroot: http://www.domain.com/
$objectpath: epages/xxx.sf/de_DE/?ObjectPath
$ratingurl: %3D%2FShops%2F15456062%2FProducts%2F%2522Briefkastenst%25C3%25A4nder%2520Bobiround%2522%2FSubProducts%2F%2522Briefkastenst%25C3%25A4nder%2520Bobiround%2520gr%25C3%25BCn%2520RAL6005%2522%26amp%3B
$viewratings: ViewAction=ViewProductRating
```

And at last I chain them together:

```
$actualurl = $domainroot.$objectpath.$ratingurl.$viewratings;
```

Comment: It looks as if the CURLOPT_POST flag is active, although you didn't set it...

Comment: echo curl_error($ch);,You wll get "malformed"

Comment: @shin I tried it, but it outputs nothing.

Comment: @Kaktus,I tried your code,with echo curl_error($ch);,i got "malformed url",and curl_errno($ch) get error no 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you so much for your help! You made my day!

And thanks to anyone who tried to help!

It was indeed the & character who messed up. Somehow the script has the when entering the urls in the database the & to `&amp;`, which had to be changed back

```
$ratingurl = str_replace('&amp;','&',$ratingurl);
```

The url was originally fetched with preg_match_all and was entered directly into database

Answer (score 1):

The first parameter of your query string shall be properly encoded:

```
$queryString = 'ObjectPath=%2FShops%2F15456062%2FProducts%2F%22Briefkastenst' .     
'%C3%A4nder+Bobiround%22%2FSubProducts%2F%22Briefkastenst' . 
'%C3%A4nder+Bobiround+gr%C3%BCn+RAL6005' 
'&ViewAction=ViewProductRating';
```

Comment: Thank you. I am setting the url from 4 parts (Domain + firstpart + databasepart + the viewActionpart), I tried to make an urlencode on the firstpart and databasepart, but now the URL is not found on the server. What parts do I have to encode? Strange because I thought it is properly encoded

Comment: Hm strange I do not understand this answer, I tried to encode the part you said, but it results always as site not found from the server.

Comment: What do you call database part and first part from your example? You need to encode (using urlencode after having decoded any already encoded value) any values passed as parameters in the query string.

The encoding example provided have been obtained as follow (as the ObjectPath parameter value has been partially encoded):
`$objectPathValue = urlencode(urldecode('/Shops/15456062/Products/%22Briefkastenst%C3%A4nder%20Bobiround%22/SubProducts/%22Briefkastenst%C3%A4nder%20Bobiround%20gr%C3%BCn%20RAL6005%22'));`

Comment: Thank you @Thierry, I edited my question with the exact parts of the url!

Comment: In the rating URL, the leading `=` symbol (%3D) should not be present. You may need to remove it and concatenate it (without encoding) at the end of the $objectPath string value.

Comment: I've noticed you forgot to add `&amp;` leading the `$viewratings` value

Comment: This is so strange. I replaced the symbol `$ratingurl = str_replace('%3D','=',$ratingurl);` but now it does not find the site at all. The same if I add the `$amp;` there. - What I do not understand, why, when I enter the link I posted first in the question, in the browser, it gets me the correct site, but when I retrieve it via curl, it ignores just the last part of the url? Why is Curl doing this, since the url should be correct. Thank you so much I am so lost with this

Comment: No sorry my fault, I mean I took the symbol away and added it into objectpath, but the same. It shows me the not found site..?

Comment: Your browser might do the right special character espaping whereas curl doesn't behave the same in "quirks" mode. You might also try to get the proper query string from your browser development tools (network tab for instance using Google Chrome).

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! Now I at least understand where the problem comes from. The network tab unfortunatedly do not show the curl request at all. The only XHR requests are the two calls on the script, and an viewAction with some sort of currency converter and the javascript from the facebook like box

Comment: Is there any webpage where I can read more about this problem? I tried manually to encode only the / with `$ratingurl = str_replace('/','%2F',$ratingurl);` but I am still getting the page without &viewaction

Comment: I've retrieved the properly encoded url as mentioned below (using native browser developer tools):
http://flic.kr/p/eauA9U

The encoded URL would be:  
`http://www.design-shop-baalcke.de/epages/15456062.sf/de_DE/?ObjectPath=/Shops/15456062/Products/%22Briefkastenst%C3%A4nder%20Bobiround%22/SubProducts/%22Briefkastenst%C3%A4nder%20Bobiround%20gr%C3%BCn%20RAL6005%22&ViewAction=ViewProductRating`